# Moving a Repo folder from one project to another project keeping the code history - Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have a project, Let's say **Project - A** and a repo inside it as **RA**. I need to move a folder from **RA** to another folder in another Repo **RB**of Project -** B**. The problem is I want to retain the history of all the commits while doing that. Can anyone guide me through to get this done?

Comment: Do you use git or TFVC?

Comment: @Hugh Lin: I am using git. I forget to mention that I don't want to move the entire Repo, all I want is to move a folder in a particular repo of a project to another folder in another repo of another project. Thanks.

Comment: @ROSHAN You can  download the folder as zip and then upload it .Please view my update of the answer.

Comment: @ROSHAN Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For **Git**, just using the **Import Repository feature**, you can import a Git repository to your team project from other project's git repo. The newly imported repo will keep all commit history. For details,please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops).

[image]

For **TFVC**, you need to use 3rd tool, you can try it with [OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1455028.OpsHubVisualStudioOnlineMigrationUtility). You could also decide to move to Git as part of your migration. Use [git-tfs to create a local git repository with all your TFVC history](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/migrate_tfs_to_git.md) and then push that into a bare Git repository in your new team project. Or use the [TFVC import tool](https://www.visualstudio.com/learn/migrate-from-tfvc-to-git/). You can refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47507154/how-to-migrate-team-project-with-history-within-same-vsts-account) for details.

**Update:**
You can download the folder as Zip,Then upload the unzip files to the folder of another project's repo .

[image]
[image]

Comment: Want to preserve history ,please refer to this [solution](http://gbayer.com/development/moving-files-from-one-git-repository-to-another-preserving-history/)

Comment: @ROSHAN Does the solution work for you?If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: Got the solution from the link you have provided and it worked for me. Thanks @Hugh Lin.

Comment: Glad to help you.Have a nice day :)

Comment: History looks preserved when I did it

Answer (score 1):

1.Download the code from Source repo:

```
git clone $sourceRepoURL  $sourceRepoFolder --single-branch --branch master
```

2.Create master branch in Target repo - either using Portal or Git

3.Upload the code to Target repo:

```
git remote add --mirror=fetch target $targetRepoURL
git push target --all
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want to move the entire Repo. Just a folder in it to another folder in another Repo of another project.

Comment: if you want the history, then I don't think that is possible for a folder - only way I can think of is to remove all other files/folder post upload.

Comment: thanks @Scorpio. I have got a solution from the above.

Comment: no problem. it would be worth posting here - in case someone else has the same requirement!